# do auto-commit slow down the performance?

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm refactoring some code written in Java with postgresql and the auto-commit mode is on. Therefore the application is slow. is there any performance benchamark?

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the code.
If you are updating many records an autocommit can decrease performances.
It happens because every transaction take a quantity of time and having autocommits you have one transaction per command.

Additionally one error in the middle of your process can not be rollbacked.

So use commits around the whole process or if you need to handle a very big group of updates around a reasonable group of operations.